# Тесты RAID-массивов

Tags: testng, raid

Подскажите некоторые моменты с этой статьи https://habr.com/company/raidix/blog/420837/

1. с помощью какого по проводилось Тест 1 Тестирование аппаратной части.
2. Читал о RAID, как я понял в статье 12 жестких дисков в которые по очереди записываться информация, почему в Тест 2. Тестирование MDRAID

> Мы все прекрасно понимаем, что построение RAID 0 на 12 дисках требует
>   особой **храбрости**

почему храбрости, что не так при этом тесте?

3. Читал о RAID0 и RAID6 - разница в тесте только в том, что в RAID6 инициализируют массив, но я все же не понимаю каким тогда образом тестируют RAID0 без инициализации массива. В чем собственно разница.

Comment: Изучите различия между уровнями RAID. RAID0 не имеет никакой формы избыточности, поэтому для его использования нужна храбрость и по той же самой причине у него нет начальной синхронизации накопителей. А какое по - лучше спросить у автора статьи. Или для этой статьи read&comment заблокированы?

Comment: @Мелкий Лично для меня заблокированы :( Просто хотел узнать какие в основном используют.